# screen or activity transition CUBE animation

Tags: android

I am building a kids game that is supposed to have 4 separate games in it. 
The idea is to switch between games by using two fingers to swipe screen, which will result in a cube rotate animation (in the direction of swipe) onto the next cube face containing the next game. Potentially six games using top and bottom cube faces.

Each game would have its own layout, potentially separate activity.

Best I could come up with for implementing cube rotation animation is [this OpenGL tutorial](http://insanitydesign.com/wp/projects/nehe-android-ports/), but I am not sure if this is the best approach.

Is there a better solution for screen/activity transition animation that anyone can suggest?

Thanks!

Comment: Try
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16746795/3d-cube-animation-in-android