# 3d Cube Animation in Android

Tags: android, android-animation

I want 3d cube transition change view or activity in android. I am searching google lot of ways but, could not find any useful resource in android.
I have found some apps in play shop with my expected animation for change view or activity. My expected output screen would be like:

[image]

I tried with transitions between but couldn't get expected result. By searching i find only animation 3d effect filp between view or activity.

can any one help me with how to get 3d cube transition between views or activities?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [3D "cube" animation between Activities in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740429/3d-cube-animation-between-activities-in-android)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Import [this project](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/JazzyViewPager) and mark as Library in project property  and add it to your project.

Create your activity like this:

```
package com.example.testcube;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.jfeinstein.jazzyviewpager.JazzyViewPager;
import com.jfeinstein.jazzyviewpager.JazzyViewPager.TransitionEffect;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private JazzyViewPager vpage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set window fullscreen and remove title bar, and force landscape orientation
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setupJazziness(TransitionEffect.CubeOut);
    }

    private void setupJazziness(TransitionEffect effect) {
        vpage = (JazzyViewPager) findViewById(R.id.jazzy_pager);
        vpage.setTransitionEffect(effect);
        vpage.setAdapter(new MainAdapter());
        vpage.setPageMargin(0);
    }

    private class MainAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
            TextView text = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
            text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            text.setTextSize(30);
            text.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            text.setText("Page " + position);
            text.setPadding(30, 30, 30, 30);
            int bg = Color.rgb((int) Math.floor(Math.random()*128)+64, 
                    (int) Math.floor(Math.random()*128)+64,
                    (int) Math.floor(Math.random()*128)+64);
            text.setBackgroundColor(bg);
            container.addView(text, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            vpage.setObjectForPosition(text, position);
            return text;
        }
        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object obj) {
            container.removeView((View) obj);
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 10;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
            return arg0 == arg1;
        }       
    }

}
```

And in your activity XML should be

```
<com.jfeinstein.jazzyviewpager.JazzyViewPager
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/jazzy_pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

[image]

Comment: have u downloaded the above mentioned project...?just download and import as android existing project and edit main activity as mentioned that's it don't hav to import any other libray

Comment: +1 for your helping effect.i try to import but doesn't work it's shows cannot import mainactivity because the project name is in use.can you give any example project?

Comment: U already having a project named mainactivity  just rename tat one and try again

Comment: it's works beautifully thanks...but, it will work on android 2.2?

Comment: can you make this transition between two Activities?

Comment: @Gangnaminmo Ako no i don't

Comment: is there any link that you can refer?

Comment: check http://www.sfonge.com/forum/topic/3d-transition-animation-between-activities & http://www.intransitione.com/blog/create-a-spinning-cube-with-opengl-es-and-android/

Comment: @Akilan i tried to use zoom in animation in list view but here mJazzy.setTransitionEffect(effect); inbuilt method of view pager so i cant achieved zoom in animation in listview.
So is it possible to make listview item zoom in as scroll same as like in your example.

Comment: Is it possible to move pager both vertical and horizontal direction at a time.

Comment: can i make the same effect without background black space ?