# Cube Animation with only two Images in an ImageView

Tags: android, animation

I need to show an Image on ImageView & onClick of that Image , I wanna show another image on  that imageView only with some Cube-like Transition Animation as shown in the below figure with "onTouch" .

[image]

I have been searching some examples on this site which , all are intended for an activity .I need to implement it for an ImageView .

Presently I am using some ViewFlipper with two images and trying to implement it,

```
<ViewFlipper android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/a"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <ImageView 
        android:contentDescription="@string/action_settings"
    android:id="@+id/alphaA"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/a"/>

    <ImageView 
        android:contentDescription="@string/action_settings"
    android:id="@+id/imgA"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/small_aeroplane1"/>
</ViewFlipper>
   ..........
```

like that I have 4 View Flippers upto now.

**I need to know , how to add cube transitions for the above case. OR is there any better way to implement CUBE TRANSITION between only two images**

Comment: Hey did you got any answer or github repository??? if yes, can you please share links here...

Comment: Sorry Learner, My client changed requirement temporarily from "cube" to "flip" effect, so I dropped that idea at that moment. If you find any please message me here...

Comment: hey @sai after Googling half an hour I got some usefull links.. I have mentioned below.

Comment: This can help you. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16746795/3d-cube-animation-in-android/16746877](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16746795/3d-cube-animation-in-android/16746877)

Answer (score 1):

I think these two links will help you in your future projects.

1) https://code.google.com/p/transitionviewpager/source/browse/

2) https://github.com/jfeinstein10/JazzyViewPager

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use ViewPager,

check https://github.com/jfeinstein10/JazzyViewPager

or here is a ready ViewPager class with 3D cube animation
https://github.com/inovex/ViewPager3D/blob/master/src/de/inovex/android/widgets/ViewPager3D.java

Comment: I need to apply the animation "onTouch" , not "onSwipe" please.

Comment: use any of the methods in the answer above, then create a button and inside its onclick listener add viewPager.setCurrentItem(position)